# Complicated 'Version-like' query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Sorry for my title, it seems a little bit 'off' but couldn't find a better one explaining my problem.

So, I have a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE DocumentTable 
(
 id int identity primary key, 
 ParentId int, 
 CategoryId int,
 Version int
);
```

This is used for storing documents and keeping track of their version.

Is it possible to have an SQL that returns the latest Version documents? Or should I go and do this programmatically (that will lower performance by a lot, since I would select all Documents and then do the manipulations)

Here is also an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d2aa) of my table with sample data.

For example I have this data in my Fiddle:

```
ID  PARENTID    CATEGORYID  VERSION 
1   (null)          1           1 
2   1               1           2 
3   2               1           3 
4   (null)          1           1 
5   (null)          1           1 
6   (null)          1           1 
7   4               1           2
```

The `Id` distinguishes the Document. The `parentId` shows witch document is the parent of it. So in my example I have 1 document with three version (1,2,3), 2 documents with no parent (5,6) and another document with 2 versions(4,7)

So for this data I want to select documents with id = 3,5,6,7

Comment: So what are the desired results? How are the same documents distinguished?

Comment: You are asking for a SQL Query that returns the documents with the highest version?

Comment: Rows `4,5,6` are the same as far as I can see. So why do you want `5,6`?

Comment: The Id distinguishes the Document. The parentId shows witch document is the parent of it. So in my example I have 1 document with three version (1,2,3), 2 documents with no parent (5,6) and another document with 2 versions(4,7)

Comment: I see! So it is a linked list in one direction.

Comment: @MartinSmith yeap! Exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   DocumentTable DT1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM   DocumentTable DT2
                  WHERE  DT2.ParentId = DT1.id)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d2aa/20)

Comment: That's a genius answer, I never could have find it on my own :) Not enough words to thank you !!